# PAYPAL RESTful API execute call occasional error

Tags: paypal

I have fully integrated my website with paypal using  paypal RESTful's API PHP SDK. Now my problem is every once in a while on the payment process, once the user approves the payment and it comes back to my website for execution, the API execution request comes back with the following responses from paypal. The HTTP response code's in these scenarios are 400 and 500. Below I have listed the error name and error message which comes as a part of the JSON response I get form paypal on execute action (https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/execute):

400 PAYMENT_NOT_APPROVED_FOR_EXECUTION,Payer has not approved payment
500 INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR,An internal service error has occurred

In terms of the code I use to make that call I have added the function which executes the payment. I should add that this is working in 98% of times. Below is the code:

```
public function getExecute()
{
    // Payment is cancelled
    if (!(Input::get('success') && Input::get('success') == 'true')) 
        return $this->runPaymentExitProcess();

    // No paymentId
    if (!Session::has('paymentId')) 
        return "No payment id to execute";

    $paymentId = Session::get('paymentId');


    $this->payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $this->apiContext);

    // The payer_id is added to the request query parameters when the user is redirected from paypal back to your site
    $this->execution->setPayer_id(Input::get('PayerID'));

    $response = $this->payment->execute($this->execution, $this->apiContext);


    // Check for paypal errors
    if (isset($response->name)) {
        // When we have a paypal error
        if ($this->hasPaypalError($response)) {
            $error = array('name' => $response->name, 'message' => $response->message);


    Session::put('error', $error);

            return (MODE == 'LIVE') ? Redirect::to('/paypalerror') : Redirect::to('/paypalerror'.MODE_PARAM);
            die;
        }   
    }   

    // Unset session
    Session::forget('paymentId');

    // execution successful
    if ($this->addPaymentIdToUser($paymentId))
        return (MODE == 'LIVE') ? Redirect::to('/') : Redirect::to('/'.MODE_PARAM);

}
```

The code is in laravel. Please note that the $this->apiContext is set in the constructor of the class. Also this is the function is the success url which is set in the API under redirect_urls.

Can someone please help me figure out if this issue is coming from my side or Paypal's side?

Comment: I get the same  error occasionally. Did you resolve this at all??

Answer (score 0):

For the 400 error, this would occur if the user decided not to approve the payment.  If you think the payment was actually approved in the web flow then that would be an issue to look into further.

Can you provide the debugId and approximate time (with timezone, or GMT) of a 500 internal server error response, and a 400 if you believe the payment was actually approved by user.

Comment: I think, I am not sure that when the user decides to go ahead with the payment Paypal goes to a page which has got a next button, but in few seconds it will redirect to the success url provided. If between the time the page loads and redirects someone clicks that next button it will comeback with 400. I had experienced this personally once.

In regards to the 500 and generally all the other errors I have created an error logger which will add error entries to my DB. Here is an export:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22602637/paypal-errors-20-09-2013.xls

Please have a look

Comment: Can you add debug id to the report?  This should be part of the response payload.

Comment: same error using sandbox.. few debug id : 1d1f9b0a6c042, ed7d6d3e0ed17

Comment: In the payments (debug ids) provided the payment was not approved, which is why the 400 error is returned.